# Is Wilcoxon test still valid if there is some shared information?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have $N$ samples from a population, and to each sample I apply both method A and method B, recording the time each takes to run  ($T_A$ and $T_B$, say)

I then define a new pseudo-measurement for each sample:
$$P_A = \frac{\min (T_A, T_B)}{T_A}$$
and
$$P_B = \frac{\min (T_A, T_B)}{T_B}$$

i.e. how much better the (somehow magically known ahead of time) best method is than the individual methods.

I now want to answer the questions:

1. Is method A and/or method B significantly better than the best of the two?
2. Is this pseudomeasurement for A different to that for B?

As the data is not at all normal, I'm using the Wilcoxon nonparametric tests.
In the case of (1), the H0 is $median(P_A)=1$, H1 $median(P_A)<1$ (and another test for B). In the case of (2), the H0 is $median(P_A)=median(P_B)$, H1 they are different, using a paired test.

**My question: am I breaking any rules in how I'm using these tests, or making some grievous errors?** The results I'm getting "make sense", so far. My main concern is that $P_A$ and $P_B$ are sharing information, but I feel like because I'm using a paired test that isn't (too much of a?) problem.

Comment: For every case ("sample") one of the 2 values coming from the 2 formulas is 1. Do you think it is good at all to have such half-constrained data? Might a single measure say, something like `(Ta-Tb)/max(Ta,Tb)` or `(Ta-Tb)/(Ta+Tb)`, suit better your needs?